# angular-ui: ui-router dynamic routes and states

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

I have a dynamic route defined as:

```
$urlRouterProvider
    .when(
        '/:resource?collection&type&id',
        [
            '$match', '$stateParams',
            function routeValidator( $match , $stateParams )
            {
                var path = '';
                angular.forEach($match, function joinner( val , key )
                {
                    if ( angular.isDefined(val) ) path += '/' + val;
                });
                return path;
            }
        ]
    )
    .when( '' , '/about' )
    .when( '/' , '/about' )
    .otherwise( '/404' );
```

And then several states:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('about',
        {
            "url":          "/about",
            "templateUrl":  "about.tmpl"
        }
    )
    //…
```

I try hitting `index.html#/` or `index.html#/about`, and none of my states are getting invoked (and subsequently none of my controllers). BUT my routes are obeyed (ex '' gets redirected to '/about'). No console errors and values return as expected (ex. for `index.html#/about`, $match & path = `/about`).

## Edit

It seems Require is part of the issue:

- [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/jshado1/vuR3k/4/) it's working in jsfiddle without require.
- [Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/JJ3WUG2k9eHxuDcgVT6P) it's *not* working in plunker with require.

Comment: The first thought is how about using `$locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');` and link as `index.html!#/about` Algularjs sometime has a mess with hashtags

Comment: Just tried that. Nothin' :/ Sidenote: hashPrefix('!') prepends to the route after the # symbol: `index.html#!/about`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Turn's out I'm an idiot: When I switched from ngRouter to ui.router, I forgot to switch `ng-view` to `ui-view`. Working plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZckIBlayuB10hooJ0sY5